# how to send only date in api with material-ui-pickers

Tags: reactjs

hi i am using react with axios and i m using material-ui-pickers date pickers but there some issue regarding date post. when i select the date and post the value i get in api **2021-11-04T01:07:00.000Z** formate but i want post only **2021-11-04**.

i am using https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker

https://material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/form-integration

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils} >
      <DatePicker value={this.state.open_Date}       
        format="dd/MM/yyyy"disableFuture
        views={["year", "month", "date"]} 
        onChange={date => this.handleUserIDChange(date)}
        // onChange={this.handleUserIDChange} 
        />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `format` in the API. But without importing a 3rd party library you can do:

```
onChange={date => {
    let d = new Date(date)
    d = `${d.getDate()}-${d.getMonth()}-${d.getFullYear()}`
    this.handleUserIDChange(d)
}
```

EDIT:
I just realized you linked version 3 docs. I was referencing this
https://mui.com/api/date-picker/
Double check your mui version.

Comment: currently i am using old version